# Traefik v2 404 page not found for docker compose service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Here is a docker compose file

```
version: "3"
networks:
  vester-net:
    name: vester-net

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro        # It's not recommended mounting the docker socket into a container -> see https://github.com/wollomatic/traefik2-hardened
    networks:
      - vester-net
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker --accessLog
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
 
  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami:v1.8
    networks:
      - vester-net
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.mywhoami.rule=(Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/whoami`))

  simplified_flask:
    build:
      context: ./apps/score
    networks:
      - vester-net
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.myflask.rule=(Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/flask`))
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080, everything goes well: it redirects to traefik dashboard and it works.

When I go to http://localhost/whoami, everything goes well: I see whoami infos

When I go to http://localhost/flask, it says 404 page not found.

I would love to have the community support on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have set up Traefik to route requests to different services based on the URL path. Your "404 page not found" error might be due to a misconfiguration in the Traefik labels for this service.

```
+------------------+          +-----------------+          +------------------+
|                  | 80, 8080 |                 |          |                  |
|     Traefik      +---------->  whoami service |          | simplified_flask |
|                  |          |                 |          |     service      |
+------------------+          +-----------------+          +------------------+
      ^      |                    /whoami                        /flask
      |      |                      ^                              ^
      |      |                      |                              |
      |      +----------------------+------------------------------+
      |
      +-- Traefik Dashboard (http://localhost:8080)
```

Make sure the Traefik labels for your `simplified_flask` service are correctly configured. The `traefik.http.routers.myflask.rule` should correctly define the host and path prefix. (`- traefik.http.routers.myflask.rule=(Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/flask`))`)

Use the [Traefik dashboard](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/) to inspect the routers and services. Look for the router corresponding to your Flask application (e.g., myflask). Check if the router is properly configured and linked to the correct service.

And check the logs of the Traefik container (`docker logs [traefik_container_name]`) to see if there are any errors or warnings related to the `simplified_flask` service.

Make sure your Flask application is configured to serve content on the root (`/`) or the specified path prefix (`/flask`). If it is expecting a different base path, it might respond with a 404 error.
For that, open the Flask application code, typically found in the directory specified in the context of the `simplified_flask` service in `docker-compose.yml`.

---

> What would you have done?

I would start from an existing Traefik-Flask tutorial/example, and then modify it to match my use case.

From example, start from [`testdrivenio/flask-docker-traefik`](https://github.com/testdrivenio/flask-docker-traefik) propose a good starting point.

Also, the article "[Flask, Gunicorn, Docker and Traefik](https://paulmarriott.medium.com/flask-gunicorn-docker-and-traefik-26fa505f5945)" from Paul Marriott can give you some ideas.

Comment: What would you have done ? Because as you see in the docker compose file, it's all correctely configured unless I miss something that you saw.

Comment: @AmonBazongo I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

change

```yaml
traefik.http.routers.myflask.rule=(Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/flask`))
```

to

```yaml
traefik.http.routers.simplified_flask.rule=(Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/flask`))
```

that way traefik knows what service to route to